# How can I export more than 4000 products in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

Im using Magento 2.3.3 and I want to export all of my product list(~4000 items). Its show this error for products export only.
[image]

Please help!!!!

Comment: May i know what os you are using?

Comment: Ubuntu 18, Apache2, PHP 7.2, Magento2.3.3

Comment: can i view your .conf file?